# How to show network error component if internet is not available in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 4 ,Here I need to check network state and display corresponding  components.

As of now error page displaying if network is not available but if I **refresh** the browser it moves to the home page **even the network is not available**.

service.ts

```
  this.onlineStatusService.status.subscribe((status: OnlineStatusType) => {
     this.status = status;
      this.InternetStatus.next(this.status);
    });
  }

  public InternetStatus = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.status);
  _InternetStatus = this.InternetStatus.asObservable();
```

Here I get the network status .

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor( private Service:Service, private router: Router) {

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.router.navigate(['/loader']);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    setTimeout( ()=>{
      this.Service._InternetStatus.subscribe( data => { 
        if( data == 0)
          this.router.navigate(['/offline']);
          else
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      });
    }, 5000)
  }
}
```

Whenever I refresh the browser window the network status is set to 'undefined'.

Reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-online-status

can anyone help me to solve this .

Answer (score 0):

use the catchError to redirect to page if the network is down.

```
this.Service._InternetStatus
     .pipe(
        catchError((error) => {.
           console.log(error)
           this.router.navigate(['/offline']);
       })
    )
     .subscribe( data => { 
        if( data == 0)
          this.router.navigate(['/offline']);
          else
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);


});
```

Comment: got this error : 'error' is declared but its value is never read.@Sachila Ranawaka